# "How to fix 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tbody'' error in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

**I expected a csv file created with in my desktop directory.**

import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import pandas as pd

```
url = "https://basketball.realgm.com/ncaa/conferences/Big-12- 
Conference/3/Kansas/54/nba-players"

# get permission
response = requests.get(url)

# access html files
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

 # creating data frame
columns = ['Player', 'Position', 'Height', 'Weight', 'Draft Year', 'NBA 
Teams', 'Years', 'Games Played','Points Per Game', 'Rebounds Per Game', 
'Assists Per Game']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

table = soup.find(name='table', attrs={'class': 'tablesaw','data- 
tablesaw-mode':'swipe','id': 'table-6615'}).tbody

trs = table.find('tr')

# rewording html

for tr in trs:
   tds = tr.find_all('td')
   row = [td.text.replace('\n', '')for td in tds]
   df = df.append(pd.Series(row, index=columns), ignore_index=True)


df.to_csv('kansas_player', index=False)
```

**I expected a csv file created with in my desktop directory.**

Comment: Please help i just getting started into web parsing.

Comment: what if `soup.find('table')` cannot find any table?

Comment: Please post the full traceback, it helps to know where the error is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like by your way the soup.find(...) can not find 'table', and that's might 
 be why you get a None type returned, here is my change and you can tailor it to cope with you csv export need:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

url = "https://basketball.realgm.com/ncaa/conferences/Big-12-Conference/3/Kansas/54/nba-players"

# get permission
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

# access html files
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find("table", {"class": "tablesaw"})
```

At this point, you can return full `table` content as:
[image]

From there on, you can easily extract the table row information by such as:

```
for tr in table.findAll('tr'):
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [td.text.replace('\n', '')for td in tds]
    .....
```

Now each row would look like:
[image]

Finally, you can write each row into the csv with or without the pandas, your call then.